# openshift python mongodb local

Tags: python, mongodb, openshift, bottle

I have a bottle+mongo application running in openshift. when I git-clone the application to my local computer neither the database nor the env-variables get download on my computer --just the  python files. Should I have to mimic the mongo part in my local computer to developed locally? Or I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to run your own Mongodb server locally or port forward and use the OPENSHIFT Mongodb.